# Proper way to write down a range with units

Tags: units

The task is to document that the r-coordinate lasts from 10 to 100 m.

What would be a good way to write this down?
I thought about the following examples

```
r = 10 to 100 [m]
r = [10 - 100 [m]]
r = 10 - 100 [m]
r = 10 [m] - 100 [m]
r = [10 - 100] [m]
```

Any further/better ideas? I could not really find any standard or something which recommends something. I am aware of the sunits siunitx ... but it does not
use square brackets. Am I just wrong here to use it?

PS: Is there a way to write tex using mathjax? I would assume so.

Comment: mathjax isn't enabled on this site

Comment: oh I see you write a "full" tex document. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some variations with package [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \SIrange{10}{100}{\metre}

  \SIrange[range-units = brackets]{10}{100}{\metre}

  \SIrange[range-units = brackets, range-phrase = --]{10}{100}{\metre}

  \SIrange[range-phrase = --]{10}{100}{\metre}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package is the best LaTeX package for typesetting physical quantities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SIrange{10}{100}{\m}

\SIrange[range-units = brackets]{10}{100}{\m}

\SIrange[range-phrase = --]{10}{100}{\m}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update** Damn. I didn't see that Heiko had already posted a [similar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184818/15874).